# Learning to Display Posts by Taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the situation, I have a custom tax called *Skill*. I want to be able to display posts only with skill set as Japanese from English.

I am trying to learn how to use *pre_get_posts* hook to modify my *get_posts* query. Here is my example, however I land with the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: postdata

This is what I have tried based on research:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpshout_fundraiser_recent_posts' );
function wpshout_fundraiser_recent_posts( $query ) {

    // Fetch only posts tagged with "Japanese from English"
    $taxquery = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Japanese from English',
            'field' => 'skill',
            'terms' => array( 'skill' ),
        )
    );
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
```

I am sure something is wrong with the above query, which I don't fully understand. Any help and please explain what each field of the array is for if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this below code this should work,

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpshout_fundraiser_recent_posts' );
function wpshout_fundraiser_recent_posts( $query ) {

$posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'Your Post Type Name',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'Japanese from English',
                'field' => 'skill',
                'terms' => array( 'skill' ),
            )
        )
    )
);
return $posts_array;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check:

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'post_type' => 'Post Type Name',
'tax_query' => array(
 array(
'taxonomy' => 'category_taxonomy',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => "Category Name"
)));
$query = query_posts( $args );
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
```

[view more](http://www.ccode4u.com/get-post-by-category-id-in-custom-post-type.html)

Comment: Does the variable postdata display the results or something so saying its undefined means?

Comment: How should my function be used to retrieve the posts by skill term

Comment: How can i use this query in the pre_get_posts function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post_type_name',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $cat->term_id,
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: How do i get the values i need for taxonomy, field and terms?

Comment: //Returns All Term Items for "taxonomy-name"
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy-name, array("fields" => "all"));
print_r($term_list);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code :

```
            $custom_args=array(
              'post_type'   => "Your Post Type Name",
              'post_status'     => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page'  => -1, 
              'caller_get_posts'=> -1,
              'hierarchical'    => 1,
              'exclude'         => '',
              'include'         => '',
              'number'          => '',
              'tax_query'       => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'Your taxonomy slug',
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' =>"'Your Category Name"
                                        )
                                    ),
             'orderby'          => 'id',
             'order'            => 'ASC'
            );
            $custom_my_query = null;
            $custom_my_query = new WP_Query($custom_args);
            $custom_my_total_count = count($custom_my_query);
            if( $custom_my_query->have_posts() ) 
            {
                    while ($custom_my_query->have_posts()) : $custom_my_query->the_post(); 
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID);?></a>
                        <?php
                      endwhile;
            }
            wp_reset_query($custom_my_query);  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    }
```